# Help with a RS232 (+-12 Volts) to USB converter

Tags: usb, uart, converter, 12v, rs232

I have a device I want to communicate to with the following signals:

[image]

This is a programmable power supply, an IPS-405. I have determined from the image above, which is all that is available in the manual, that I need a RS232 to USB converter (null modem) that works at 12 Volts, but I haven't been able to find any, or there is a lot of confusion regarding this converters.

Since I am trying to avoid buying a cable that does not work and have to return it later, can anyone recommend where to buy a RS232 to USB converter with these characteristics? Or chipsets? I have been looking at PL2303 but some reviews mention it works at +-6V, so I guess it also depends on the cable.

EDIT 1

So according to this schematic: https://ibb.co/NxJ1xpt, which seems to be of the PSU or a very similar model, the 12V signal is probably just feeding the optocouples and it is not a RS232 signal. I am still confused about what kind of cable I need to interact with this PSU though, I would rather avoid having to build a custom one.

EDIT 2

I also looked at the datasheet of the Winbond UC with the TXD/RXD signals, and noticed that the ranges of Input/Output for the TXD and RXD signals are in the range of 0V to 5V it seems: https://ibb.co/n3Ybpfq.

So it looks like a 12V input, a normal UART and a RS232 connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost none of the USB to RS-232 adapters will use 12V. They typically use charge pumps to boost 5V or 3.3V to acceptable RS-232 levels, i.e. the output just has to exceed 5V when connected into standard RS-232 load,

But you don't know if the device really needs 12V on that pin. It might be an RS-232 input after all, and the manual might simply mean to connect DTR there to see when the port is used.

Also the pinout is very atypical because pins 2&3 need to be crossed but pin 4 is connected directly. Null modem cables do swap pins 2&3 but also 4&6. You need a custom cable.

Edit:

After seeing the schematics, the optocoupler N13 LED must be off when idle and on when PC transmits. I think pin 2 is TXD from PC and pin 4 is GND. The optocoupler N14 LED is on when idle, so if again pin 4 is GND, pin 3 is RXD to PC, and therefore pin 1 is the DTR signal for providing bias voltage for PC.

There is a good chance that it will simply work with any USB to RS-232 serial adapter, but you still need a special cable to connect the pins as drawn.

A straight through cable will connect pins as follows : 5-5 and 4-4 but will also connect 2-2 and 3-3. A null-modem cable will connect 5-5, 2-3, 3-2 as expected, but will also connect 4-6 and 6-4.

You need to modify the cable somehow to make the connection 4-4 between devices.

Comment: So I think I managed to get some clarity of this, it is not a standard RS232, and the 12V constant signal seems to feed a pair of optocouples. I have added the schematic of the PSU to the main post.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I also looked at the datasheet of the Winbond UC with the txd and rxd signals and I believe it is just a 0V to 5V UART, couple of things to try tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a shopping question and these are generally frowned upon, but I’m inclined to think that it’s general enough to be of use to the wider community.  I’d have a high degree of confidence that anything claiming to be RS232 and terminating in a DE-9 connector is 12V compatible.  Devices that terminate in 0.1” pin headers are typically 3V.  The interface chip (PL2303 etc) could be used with either type, the difference being that RS232 has an additional 12V driver IC.

Comment: Sorry, did not really intend it to be a shopping question, I just didn't know to ask for guidance regarding which cable to buy because there seems to be quite a lot of confusion around this. I have one usb to rs232 cable with that chipset that does not work, it only puts +-6 Volts, apparently some old machines only work at +-12 Volts and reject other voltages and I fear this is the case of my programmable power supply.

Comment: The RS232 spec calls for somewhere between 3 and 15 volts positive and negative.  So-called TTL UARTs use 0 and 3.3V or thereabouts.  +/-6V is in the RS232 range and so that should work for devices that meet the RS232 standard.  There’s no guarantee that non-compliant devices will work, of course.  The PSU you’re interfacing to appears to use 4 and 5 as 12V and ground, which is not standard.  You may be able to communicate if you just connect pins 2,3 and 5 though.

Comment: I have added some more information to the main post, I think the 12V input is just to feed a pair of optocouples for isolation purposes, and TX, RX, GND are the only RS232 signals in the connector.